# Google Map Infowindow Not Appearing Properly

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I have a standard Google Map Infowindow being opened on click on a standard Google Marker. The arrow pointing down to the marker seems to be a couple of pixels off. I have been banging my head against the wall trying to figure out what properties in my CSS are affecting it.  The ZURB Foundation framework properties affecting img { max-width: 100% } were causing some other problems, but I was able to track that down and adjust. I can't seem to find the cause of this one though. I am using ZURB v4 and GMapsv3.

http://stage2.curran-connors.com/reliance/index.php/contact/

Click a marker and you will see the arrow starts just below the border of the info window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zurb Foundation sets the *box-sizing* style on everything to *border-box*.  This causes the alignment error that you are seeing in the Google Maps info window.

The fix:

```
#map_container div {
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Pete, appreciate your help.  I actually thought that was the issue, but turning it off globally in Firebug did not seem to give me the results I was looking for. I should have played with it some more. Your solution worked great. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem I have faced, controls were not showing and `Infowindow` was not appearing properly. JavaScript shows,

> Uncaught Type Error: undefined is not a function.

Commenting/removing the following code from prototype.js resolved my problem

```
this.each(function(value, index) {

      results.push(iterator.call(context, value, index));
});
```

Comment: Zeeshan, it does not seem like we were experiencing the same problem. My JavaScript was working just fine, no errors. I was having problems styling the Google Map InfoWindow to appear in the correct position over a Google Map Marker.  Pete Parker's CSS fix moved the InfoWindow into the correct position by adjusting the box-sizing property as explained in his answer.